# How to include a jar file into Scala code

Tags: java, scala, jar, sbt

This is the Scala code that I have written

```
object Main extends App {
    println("Hello World from Scala!")
}
```

This is my build file

```
name := "hello-world"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.5"

mainClass := Some("Main")
```

This is command that I am using to create the jar file

`java -cp "scala-library.jar:target/scala-2.11/hello-world_2.11-1.0.jar" Main`

Problem: I want to include the *scala-library.jar* in my hello-world jar file so that I don't have to reference it in the command line. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I use it is add all the external jar to the "lib" folder and use "sbt assembly" to create one fat jar.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you bundle the jar file into your applications jar file. you can use jar command for packaging or any such utility offered by the IDE as well.